# Breeze.js and TimeSpan ISO literals

Tags: c#, knockout.js, breeze, timespan, momentjs

My C# server-side model has a TimeSpan property (Used to store a time of day) which on retrieval by Breeze is returned as an ISO literal for timespans. So a TimeSpan of 9hrs (09:00) is returned as 'PT9H'. What is the best way to convert this to and from a more user friendly string of 09:00 (which will be constrained by a UI timepicker widget)?

I am using Knockout to bind to my HTML elements.

Comment: It's not been merged yet, but [a pull request](https://github.com/moment/moment/pull/941) for ISO duration parsing was recently added to [moment.js](http://momentjs.com).  So the *next* release of moment.js will be able to handle this.

Comment: So I'd use a Knockout computed to do the conversion with moment.js? Could you stick your comment in an answer so I can credit it? Thanks.

Comment: You could also create a custom binding handler to convert your format to 9:00 in the interim.  This would be a perfect scenario for a binding handler

Comment: I'd rather wait to see if others have a solution you can use today.  I can always come back here and answer again after the next release of moment.js.

Comment: @kadumel - Excellent suggestion.  A few people have already done that for regular moments, such as [this guy](http://www.jones.bz/index.php/2013/04/17/format-dates-using-knockout-js-custom-bindings-with-moment-js/).  It would be slightly different for a moment.duration, but the same general approach could be used.

Comment: I'm not sure I can use a custom binding here as a simple 2 way value converter. If in the init: part I add a handler to the element's change event to update the viewmodel's property and back the other way, with the viewmodel property observable updating the element on change.. won't I get a loop of each updating each other?? The viewmodel property needs to update the element because I allow the user to revert property values (using Breeze) if they cancel their edit. It seems the only solution left is a computed observable on the viewmodel to do the conversion. Anyone have a regex which works?

Answer (score 5):

The best solution for dealing with ISO 8601 durations I've found is to use a moment-isoduration plugin for moment.js library. Repo: https://github.com/dordille/moment-isoduration

Using your example:

```
var duration = moment.duration.fromIsoduration('PT9H');
```

That returns a duration object that has a _milliseconds property, so calling

```
moment.utc(duration._milliseconds).format('hh:mm')
```

Should return "09:00"

Comment: this functionality has now been merged into the moment library, and the plugin is therefore deprecated